# lookup table vs runtime computation efficiency - C++

Tags: c++, performance, caching, optimization, lookup-tables

My code requires continuously computing a value from the following function:

```
inline double f (double x) {
    return ( tanh( 3*(5-x)  ) *0.5 + 0.5);
}
```

Profiling indicates that this part of the program is where most of the time is spent. Since the program will run for weeks if not months, I would like to optimize this operation and am considering the use of a lookup table.

I know that the efficiency of a lookup table depends on the size of the table itself, and on the way it's designed. Currently I cannot use less than 100 MB and can use up to 2GB. Values between two points in the matrix will be linearly interpolated.

Would using a lookup table be faster than doing the computation? Also, would using an N-dimensional matrix be better than a 1-D std::vector and what is the threshold (if any) on the size of the table that should not be crossed?

Comment: Even if that function is where most of the time is spent, is the time to a detriment to the rest of the program? Using tables and extrapolation may be faster, but is it worth _your_ time to do this optimization? And will it help the people using your program? And remember, unless the people using your program start complaining about it being slow, do you really need it?

Comment: yes, definitely. We're talking about something that will run for weeks not to say months. I tried my best to optimize everything else before. This seems to me a nice possibility.

Comment: I think you'll be more likely to get high-quality help if you showed us the relevant code (ideally as part of an SSCCE - http://sscce.org/). Otherwise IMO the question is a little too abstract.

Comment: *I'm not allowed to use less than 10 MB* - is this some restriction your teacher's putting on your use of a lookup table?  That seems very odd.

Comment: @NPE I hope the function itself is enough. The function argument itself requires some calculation, and using a lookup table could be useful also in that regard.

Comment: @TonyD the restrictions come from some precision requirements I have.

Comment: If your program takes months to run, and you think this might help, just do it and measure the impact.  Not worth wasting time here asking about it.  You might also do a bit of Internet searching for fast alternative tanh functions, as that must be where it's spending most of its time.  If you have any knowledge about the x values coming in, it might suggest other optimisations - such as a caching approach rather than a lookup table: that gives you a lot more control over memory usage.

Comment: If you would have huge lookup table (hundreds of MB as you said), which does not fit to cache - most likely memory lookup time would be much higher than calculation itself. RAM is "very slow".

Comment: @TonyD of course on monday this will be my task. My question, however, was about how to design the table.

Comment: `tanh` of `15 - 3x` reaches the horizontal asymptotes of 1 and -1 by roughly 1 and 9 respectively. You really only need to calculate it for a small range of `x`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm writing a code that continuously requires to compute a value from a particular function. After some profiling, I discovered that this part of my program is where most of the time is spent.
>
> So far, I'm not allowed to use less than 100 MB, and I can use up to 2GB. A linear interpolation will be used for points between to points in the matrix.

If you would have huge lookup table (hundreds of MB as you said), which does not fit to cache - most likely memory lookup time would be much higher than calculation itself. RAM is "very slow", especially when fetching from random locations of huge arrays.

Here is synthetic test:

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7239c9d5feaa5c3)

```
#include <boost/progress.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

inline double calc(double x)
{
    return ( tanh( 3*(5-x)  ) *0.5 + 0.5);
}

template<typename F>
void test(F &&f)
{
   progress_timer t;
   volatile double res;
   for(unsigned i=0;i!=1<<26;++i)
      res = f(i);
   (void)res;
}

int main()
{
   const unsigned size = (1 << 26) + 1;
   vector<double> table(size);
   cout << "table size is " << 1.0*sizeof(double)*size/(1 << 20) << "MiB" << endl;
   cout << "calc ";
   test(calc);
   cout << "dummy lookup ";
   test([&](unsigned i){return table[(i << 12)%size];}); // dummy lookup, not real values
}
```

Output on my machine is:

```
table size is 512MiB
calc 0.52 s

dummy lookup 0.92 s
```

Comment: thanks. My situation could be slightly different than this, but this example probably can point me to the right path. The reason I didn't try it myself is that there are other issues involved I didn't mention, and testing requires some work. Thanks again :)

Comment: At least in this test suite/architecture, there's an interesting jump, 0.25MiB-2MiB are ~0.59s, but 4MiB is ~1.20s, and 8MiB-32MiB are ~1.48s.  I bet there's a cache limit right about there.

Comment: @MooingDuck It is indeed related to sizes of cache levels. But note, that in this particular case, after growing out of cache - probability of "in cache" starts decrease gradually, not as sharp milestone. `getconf -a|grep -i cache` for Coliru [reports](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff1f47180fd13e5a) following cache sizes: L1=64KiB, L2=512KiB, L3=6MiB. While it is possible to investigate cache boundaries solely by benchmark, but other data access patterns are more suited for this purpose.