# When should I cache the result of a computation?

Tags: caching, cpu-cache

Is there a good way to tell whether I should cache the results of a computation? Or asked differently, under what conditions is retrieving from memory slower than recomputing?

I understand that benchmarking will give the definitive answer. However, benchmarking is quite time consuming, especially when there are many small computations to test. I'm looking for a good rule of thumb to follow, that would work well in most cases.

I assume it would have something to do with the size of the CPU's on-board memory. And probably the cache latency for RAM...

Comment: It would also depend on whether caching the result means not having to reference other data (assuming that allowing such data to be discarded or dropped from cache is not harmful to performance). The "load factor" (not just absolute capacity) of processor caches is important; if cache capacity *and bandwidth* are underutilized, then memoization of operations is less expensive. The temporal locality of reuse is also a factor. (Even probable reuse can be exploited, though the cost of even infrequent branch mispredictions makes such more expensive.)

Comment: Some software caching frameworks may be able to help you, but a HW CPU cache doesn't ask you what to cache, and can't change the program flow (including skipping any function calls)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a good way to tell whether I should cache the results of a
>   computation? Or asked differently, under what conditions is retrieving
>   from memory slower than recomputing?

I assume you are asking about using a [lookup-table (LUT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table).
 It depends on:

1. The complexity of the computations
2. The size of the LUT

If you have many results of simple computations, then recomputing could be faster.
In case you have results of complex operations that can be stored in a LUT that fits in the lower cache levels (L1, L2), the LUT could speed-up your code.

But, as you say, benchmarking will give the definitive answer.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15452481/lookup-table-vs-runtime-computation-efficiency-c) you have an example of a LUT vs. computation comparison.